# What type of images will i choose for phonegap app development to get best result in all devices.

Tags: cordova, ui-design

I want to use such an image that will load fast in all small or big android devices.

In small device it will load fast.
In big device the image quality will be good.

In such case, what size or type of images will i use for best practice?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think its depend upon the images and your requirement.

- You can use **PNG** if you required transparency or lossless
  compression.
- You can use **JPEG** if you required full color support.
- You can use **GIF** if you required animation.

If your images are simple with one or two colors then you may use CSS with some `repeat-x` or `repeat-y` properties.